# I need to ignore certain items of an array and create initials from remaining

Tags: php, arrays

I need to avoid the CN=Users, DC=aab, DC=local values that return from the array. Then save the INITIALS of  the remaining names into a new array. Any help would be appreciated. I'm just not really sure where to start.
This is how it returns right now when I do the following.

```
$reportees = $_SESSION["user"]->directreports;
$reportees = implode(",", $reportees);
```

CN=John Doe,CN=Users,DC=aab,DC=local,CN=Jane Ann Doe,CN=Users,DC=aab,DC=local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$reportees = $_SESSION["user"]->directreports;
$blacklist = array('CN=Users', 'DC=aab', 'DC=local');

$arrayOfInitials = array();
foreach($reportees as $key=>$reportee){
    // ignore the unwanted values :
    if(!in_array($reportee, $blacklist)){
        // take only the value after the "=":
        $reportee = explode("=", $reportee);
        if(isset($reportee[1])){
            $reportee = $reportee[1];
            $reporteeNames = explode(" ", $reportee);
            $initials = "";
            // get the initials :
            foreach($reporteeNames as $name){
                $initials .= strtoupper($name[0]);
            }
            $arrayOfInitials[] = $initials;
        }

    }
}

$initialsAsStr = implode(',', $arrayOfInitials);
var_dump($initialsAsStr);
```

The output will be :

```
string(10) "JD,B,JAD,B"
```

Comment: where are the initials "B" coming from?

Comment: It's because the post has been edited, there was an extra entry "DC=byl".

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$in = ['CN=John Doe','CN=Users','DC=aab','DC=local','CN=Jane Ann Doe','CN=Users','DC=aab','DC=local'];

function initials_from_value($i) {
    strtok($i, '=');
    $i          = strtok('=');
    $names      = explode(' ', $i);
    $initials   = array_map(function ($i) { return substr($i, 0, 1); }, $names);

    return $initials;
}

$out = array();
foreach($in as $item) {
    if(strpos($item, 'CN=') === 0 && $item !== 'CN=Users') {
        $out[] = implode(' ', initials_from_value($item));
    }
}

var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'J D',
  1 => 'J A D',
)
```

Addendum (Collate only first and last initials):

```
$out = array();
foreach($in as $item) {
    if(strpos($item, 'CN=') === 0 && $item !== 'CN=Users') {
        if( ($initials = initials_from_value($item)) && count($initials) >= 2) {
            $first = reset($initials);
            $last  = end($initials);
            $out[] = $first . $last;
        }
    }
}

var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'JD',
  1 => 'JD',
)
```

Comment: This one also worked, I just had to take the space out from between the letters. thank you.

Comment: How would I avoid the middle initial? So it only outputs first and last name

Comment: @Ryan, You are changing the brief!  Added example.

Comment: Sorry for changing, Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array with a closure, and have it return FALSE for unwanted items, so that it can be filtered with array_filter.

This way you can check the results incrementally, which I find easier to debug.

```
$values = array_map(
        /* Get a reportee, return the name or FALSE */
        function($reportee) {
            list($key, $value) = explode('=', $reportee);
            switch ($key) {
                case 'CN': // CN=Users or CN=Jane Ann Doe
                    if ('Users' === $value) {
                         return false;
                    }
                    // $value is now hopefully Jane Ann Doe.
                    return $value;
                default: // Anything else gets FALSEd.
                    return false;
            }
        },
        $reportees
    );

// Eliminate unwanted results:
// [ 0 => false, 1 => false, 2 => false, 3 => 'Jane Ann Doe', 4 => false ]
$values = array_filter($values);

// $values should now be something like [ 3 => 'Jane Ann Doe' ]
// Get initials.
$values = array_map(
    /* input: "Jane Ann Doe"; output: "JAD" */
    function ($value) {
        $words = preg_split('#\\s+#', $value);
        $initials = array_map(
            function ($word) {
                return substr($word, 0, 1);
            },
            $words
        );
        return implode('', $initials);
    },
    $values
);

// $values is now [ '3' => 'JAD' ].
// You can use array_values($values) to renumber the array.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (PHP >= 5.4):

```
$reportees = array('CN=John Doe',
                   'CN=Users',
                   'DC=aab',
                   'DC=local',
                   'CN=Jane Ann Doe',
                   'CN=Users',
                   'DC=aab',
                   'DC=local');
$result = [];
foreach ($reportees as $value) {
    switch ($value) {
        // ignore these values
        case 'CN=Users':
        case 'DC=aab':
        case 'DC=local':
            continue 2;

        // get initials of these values
        default:
            $expr = '/(?<=\s|^)[a-z]/i';
            preg_match_all($expr, explode('=', $value)[1], $matches);
            $result[] = strtoupper(implode('', $matches[0]));
    }
}
$reportees = implode(',', $result);
```

Result:

```
JD,JAD
```